# font awesome icon incorrect in Angular

Tags: angular, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome  icon in My Angular project.

For that I have added the following code in head of my Index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In my HTML I am  using the following code :

```
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

I am expecting Hamburger ICON with 3 horizontal Bars.
[image]

But What is Get is a rectangular Box
[image]

This is my complete HTML CODE using Bootstrap

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
```

This is my Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Frontend</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-CuOF+2SnTUfTwSZjCXf01h7uYhfOBuxIhGKPbfEJ3+FqH/s6cIFN9bGr1HmAg4fQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-t6I8D5dJmMXjCsRLhSzCltuhNZg6P10kE0m0nAncLUjH6GeYLhRU1zfLoW3QNQDF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get better results if you do this `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>` rather than `<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>`?

Comment: Make sure to put your i element outside the button element. If it's work, then please check your style and make sure you don't override the font-family of i element inside button element.

Comment: I have used "<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>" . It is also displaying  rectangular box.

Comment: I have also tried to use it outside the Button. It has same results

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome requires the class `fa` not `fas`. You would notice this if you download the linked stylesheet https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

This should work:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```